# reading out a stringstream and insert it in different vectores

Tags: c++, sfml

(I'm sorry if I ask this question wrong, this is my first time I write in a forum)

When I started programming at my SFML - Game, I had a very old book, wich was very C-like (eg. recommendation of atoi();).
Now I got a new C++(including C++11) book, and  I want to rewrite the old lines wih newer Code.

I saved the Tiles in a file stored like this:

```
[0-0,15-1|22,44] [0-1|0]
[4-0,10-1,3-1|0] [0-5,5-5|0]
```

That means:
[...] desribes a Tile
0-0 etc. is the xy position on the Texturesheet
22 etc. is the event that will be triggered.
the amount of events and sf::Vector2i shouldn't be set constantly.

The Tiles are separately taken out from another class, which manages the entire Tilemap.

Now my problem: I have no idea how i should push the numbers from the strinstream right in  two vectores?
My code:

```
class Tile{
     private:
          std::deque<sf::Sprite> tile;
      std::deque<int> event;
     public:

    Tile(sf::Texture& texture, std::deque<sf::Vector2i>&& ctor_texturerects, std::deque<int>&& ctor_events);//This one is working fine

    Tile(sf::Texture& texture, std::stringstream&& ctor_stream/*reads the Tile*/){

      std::deque<sf::Vector2i> temp_texturerects;
      std::deque<int>temp_events;
      /*TODO: filter the stringstream and push them into the containers*/
      Tile::Tile(texture,std::move(temp_texturerect),std::move(temp_events));
}
```

I'd be also very happy if you could give me another solution, like changing sf::Vector2i to a better solution or giving me a better stream and class concept
Thanks in advance
Xeno Ceph

Edit:
I made a little workaround:
(I changed the inputstream to a normal string)
But the code doesn't look good
There mujst be an easier solution

```
Tile::  Tile(sf::Texture& texture, std::string&& ctor_string){
    std::deque<sf::Vector2i> temp_texturerects;
    std::deque<int> temp_events;
    std::stringstream strstr;


    for(int i=0; i<ctor_string.size(); ++i){
        while(ctor_string[i]!='|'){

            while(ctor_string[i] != ','){
                strstr << ctor_string[i];
            }
            sf::Vector2i v2i;
            strstr >> v2i.x >> v2i.y;
            temp_texturerects.push_front(v2i);
            strstr.str("");
        }
        while(ctor_string[i]!=']'){
            while(ctor_string[i] != ','){
                strstr << ctor_string[i];
            }
            int integer;
            strstr  >> integer;
            temp_events.push_front(integer);
            strstr.str("");
        }
    }
    Tile::Tile(texture, std::move(temp_texturerects), std::move(temp_events));
}
```

Has anybody a better solution?

Comment: This line:`while(ctor_string[i] != ','){
                strstr << ctor_string[i];
            }` may give you an infinite loop because you're not incrementing `i` in the loop ... could you slightly correct your code so that we know what you're trying to do? Then it would be easier to suggest a better solution :)

Comment: Also what is your stringstream/string? Is it from the file where you store the tiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have some strings of the form

```
[0-0,15-1|22,44] [0-1|0]
[4-0,10-1,3-1|0] [0-5,5-5|0]
```

and you want to extract 2 types of data - positions (e.g. 0-0) and events (e.g. 22).
Your question is how to extract this data cleanly, discarding the `[` and `]` characters, etc.

One great way to approach this is to use the `getline` function that operates on stringstreams, which inherit from std::istream (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/). It can take custom delimiters, not just the newline character. So you can use `'['`, `'|'` and `']'` as different delimiting characters and parse them in a logical order.

For example, since your string is just a collection of tiles, you can split it up into a number of functions - `ParseTile`, `ParsePositions` and `ParseEvents`, something like the following:

```
void Tile::ParseInput(stringstream&& ctor_string) {

  //extract input, tile by tile
  while(!ctor_string.eof()) {
    string tile;

    //you can treat each tile as though it is on a separate line by
    //specifying the ']' character as the delimiter for the "line"
    getline(ctor_string, tile, ']');
    tile += "]"; //add back the ']' character that was discarded from the getline

    //the string "tile" should now contain a single tile [...], which we can further process using ParseTile
    ParseTile(tile);
  }

}
```

The ParseTile function:

```
void Tile::ParseTile(string&& tile) {
  //input string tile is e.g. " [0-0, 15-1|22,44]"

  string discard; //string to hold parts of tile string that should be thrown away
  string positions; //string to hold list of positions, separated by ','
  string events; //string to hold events, separated by ','

  //create stringstream from input
  stringstream tilestream(tile);
  //tilestream is e.g. "[0-0,15-1|22,44]"

  getline(tilestream, discard, '['); //gets everything until '['
  //now, discard is " [" and tilestream is "0-0,15-1|22,44]"

  getline(tilestream, positions, '|');
  //now, positions is "0-0,15-1" and tilestream is "22,44]"

  getline(tilestream, events,']');
  //now, events is "22,44" and tilestream is empty

  ParsePositions(positions);

  ParseEvents(events);


}
```

You can write your own ParsePositions and ParseEvents functions which basically will be a more getline calls using a ',' as the delimiting character (just loop until the string ends).

Comment: Mmm. `getline` would be the _pragmatic_ approach - as in quick and dirty. I wouldn't go so far as to describe it as "a great" way, except for... getting whole lines of input (imagine a format allowing `[[1,3],[2,4]|5]`). My $0.02 (the other $2 is in my answer)

Comment: Sure. My answer was intended to be specific to the question OP asked, and to demonstrate an easily-accessible feature of the language to improve OP's own idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest either writing a proper parser manually (not unlike the other answer proposes) or to use a proper parsing framework, like Boost Spirit.

The advantages of the latter is that you get debuggability, composability, attributes etc. "for free". Here's the simplest example I could think of:

```
struct TileData
{
    std::deque<sf::Vector2i> texturerects;
    std::deque<int>          events;
};

typedef std::deque<TileData> TileDatas;

template <typename It>
struct parser : qi::grammar<It, TileDatas(), qi::space_type>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        v2i = (int_ >> '-' >> int_) 
            [ _val = phx::construct<sf::Vector2i>(_1, _2) ];

        tiledata = 
            (v2i  % ',') >> '|' >>
            (int_ % ',');

        start = *('[' >> tiledata >> ']');
    }
    private:
    qi::rule<It, sf::Vector2i(), qi::space_type> v2i;
    qi::rule<It, TileData(),     qi::space_type> tiledata;
    qi::rule<It, TileDatas(),    qi::space_type> start;
};
```

Adding a bit of code to test this, see it live on **[http://liveworkspace.org/code/3WM0My$1](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3WM0My%241)**, output:

```
Parsed: TileData {
    texturerects: deque<N2sf8Vector2iE> {v2i(0, 0), v2i(15, 1), }
    events:       deque<i> {22, 44, }
}
Parsed: TileData {
    texturerects: deque<N2sf8Vector2iE> {v2i(0, 1), }
    events:       deque<i> {0, }
}
Parsed: TileData {
    texturerects: deque<N2sf8Vector2iE> {v2i(4, 0), v2i(10, 1), v2i(3, 1), }
    events:       deque<i> {0, }
}
Parsed: TileData {
    texturerects: deque<N2sf8Vector2iE> {v2i(0, 5), v2i(5, 5), }
    events:       deque<i> {0, }
}
```

Full code:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx= boost::phoenix;

// liveworkspace.org doesn't have SFML
namespace sf { struct Vector2i { int x, y;  Vector2i(int ax=0, int ay=0) : x(ax), y(ay) {} }; }

struct TileData
{
    std::deque<sf::Vector2i> texturerects;
    std::deque<int>          events;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(TileData,
        (std::deque<sf::Vector2i>, texturerects)
        (std::deque<int>, events))

typedef std::deque<TileData> TileDatas;

template <typename It>
struct parser : qi::grammar<It, TileDatas(), qi::space_type>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        v2i = (int_ >> '-' >> int_) 
            [ _val = phx::construct<sf::Vector2i>(_1, _2) ];

        tiledata = 
            (v2i  % ',') >> '|' >>
            (int_ % ',');

        start = *('[' >> tiledata >> ']');
    }
    private:
    qi::rule<It, sf::Vector2i(), qi::space_type> v2i;
    qi::rule<It, TileData(),     qi::space_type> tiledata;
    qi::rule<It, TileDatas(),    qi::space_type> start;
};

typedef boost::spirit::istream_iterator It;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, sf::Vector2i const &v) { return os << "v2i(" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ")"; }

template <typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::deque<T> const &d) {
    os << "deque<" << typeid(T).name() << "> {";
    for (auto& t : d) os << t << ", ";
    return os << "}";
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, TileData const& ttd) {
    return os << "TileData {\n"
        "\ttexturerects: " << ttd.texturerects << "\n"
        "\tevents:       " << ttd.events << "\n}";
}

int main()
{
    parser<It> p;

    std::istringstream iss(
            "[0-0,15-1|22,44] [0-1|0]\n"
            "[4-0,10-1,3-1|0] [0-5,5-5|0]");

    It f(iss), l;

    TileDatas data;
    if (qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::space,data))
    {
        for (auto& tile : data)
        {
            std::cout << "Parsed: " << tile << "\n";
        }
    }

    if (f != l)
    {
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f, l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even know that Boost provides a parser